# differentiate between instances of the same form with different prefixes in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am passing two form with different prefix in the template and each form has own submit button but how can I get data from these two form in submit button is pressed in any one of them and how to differentiate which form button was pressed

```
return render(request,'part_details.html', {'part_stock_form': forms.part_stock_form(prefix='add'),'part_stock_edit':forms.part_stock_form(prefix='edit')})
```

template: add_app form object

```
<form id="add_app_form" method="post" action="{% url 'parts:part_app_model' part_temp.part_id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ add_app.applicable }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

template: edit_app form object

```
  <form method="post"  action="{% url 'parts:part_app_model' part_temp.part_id %}">
    {{ edit_app.applicable }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you have 2 submit button name them and check them, like

```
<input type="submit" name="fom1">sumbit formm 1 

<input type="submit" name="fom2">sumbit formm 2 

if 'fom1' in request.POST:
    #statements
elif 'fom2' in request.POST:
    #statements
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is to check keys of POST data.
Let's say you have field1 in one form and field2 in another form, but neither is present in both the forms.

```
if 'field1' in request.POST.keys():
    #statements
elif 'field2' in request.POST.keys():
    #statements
```

Other way is sending them to different urls under action attribute of form and then define separate views for them, and configuring urls.py accordingly.
Hope it helps.

Comment: which key are you talking about? they are the instance of the same form won't they have the same key?

Comment: if you are submitting a form using POST, the django server recieves data as a django.http.request.QueryDict object. It has key-value pairs, like a python dictionary.
"request.POST.keys()" returns the list of keys.
Use these:
    "print request.POST.keys()" 
    "print request.POST"
and you can see the output in terminal where u have run the server.